# Как открыть скрытую строку в 2 разных таблицах по нажатию одной кнопки?

Tags: javascript, table

2 таблицы - в каждой из них спрятана 2 строка
(в 2 таблицах скрыты четные строки) - (`display:none`).
По нажатию на `.FixCol tr:after` - открывается следующая строка, на которую нажали (теоретически строк много) - но как сделать так, что-бы открыть и в другой таблице следующую строку - что-бы данные совпадали?

Спасибо.

Для открытия следующей строки написал такое:

```
$(".FixCol tr").click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggleClass("item-r");`
});

     <div class="FixCol">
              <table> 
              <tbody>
            <tr><td>04eebec9-69ad-4bcd-9291-b008043c2dcb</td></tr> 
             <tr><td>04eebec9-69ad-4bcd-9291-b008043c2dcb</td></tr> 
             <tr><td>06a13383-b2bf-46a1-a1a0-c615ccb2bc80</td></tr> 
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
          <div class="Content">
    <table>
     <tbody>
    <tr>  
    <td>0.57</td> <td>0.09</td> <td>0.93</td> <td>0.11</td> <td>0.61</td> <td>0.93</td> <td>0.73</td> <td>0.66</td> <td>0.2</td> <td>0.73</td> <td>0.88</td> <td>0.04</td> <td>0.84</td> <td>0.09</td> <td>0.85</td> <td>0.67</td> <td>0.52</td> <td>0.78</td> <td>0.16</td> <td>0.86</td> <td>0.62</td> <td>0.46</td> <td>0.57</td> <td>0.72</td> <td>0.51</td> <td>0.37</td> <td>0.96</td> <td>0.5</td> <td>0.06</td> <td>0.65</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
    <td>0.35</td> <td>0.3</td> <td>0.16</td> <td>0.02</td> <td>0.58</td> <td>0.76</td> <td>0.93</td> <td>0.99</td> <td>0.1</td> <td>0.03</td> <td>0.77</td> <td>0.89</td> <td>0.62</td> <td>0.37</td> <td>0.24</td> <td>0.35</td> <td>0.68</td> <td>0.44</td> <td>0.16</td> <td>0.59</td> <td>0.31</td> <td>0.1</td> <td>0.01</td> <td>0.7</td> <td>0.13</td> <td>0.63</td> <td>0.15</td> <td>0.14</td> <td>0.35</td> <td>0.21</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>  
    <td>0.84</td> <td>0.03</td> <td>0.11</td> <td>0.26</td> <td>0.53</td> <td>0.26</td> <td>0.93</td> <td>0.22</td> <td>0.0</td> <td>0.66</td> <td>0.37</td> <td>0.18</td> <td>0.38</td> <td>0.67</td> <td>0.78</td> <td>0.81</td> <td>0.8</td> <td>0.23</td> <td>0.97</td> <td>0.09</td> <td>0.8</td> <td>0.15</td> <td>0.29</td> <td>0.67</td> <td>0.61</td> <td>0.33</td> <td>0.55</td> <td>0.57</td> <td>0.2</td> <td>0.27</td>
    </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень ясно, какие строки должны открываться. То ли спрятана вторая строка, то ли их много. Возможное решение - в каждой таблице каждой строке задавать одинаковый класс `<tr class="tr1">`,  `<tr class="tr2">` и т.д.. По нажатию брать все элементы с этим классом и показывать их.

Comment: Скрыты все четные строки - в 2 таблицах - но проблема в том что таблица строится из данных - и проставить просто tr1 - tr2 - я незнаю как - плюс - непонятно тогда как открывать даже с класами

Comment: А какой элемент управления должен быть, по чему клик? По нечетной строке любой таблицы - отрывается следующая четная? Или какая-то кнопка типа "открыть следующую четную строку"?

Comment: по нечетной клик - а следующая за ней четная открывается - и в другой таблице открывается четная - то есть - номер строки в 2 таблицах которые открываются одинаковый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так примерно можно сделать. Код не очень, но главное идея понятна, надеюсь. Не заморачивался особо со стилями.

```js
$('tr').click(function () {
  // получим номер текущей строки из атрибута 'num'
  var currentTrNum = $(this).attr('num');
 if(currentTrNum % 2 != 0){
    // Если строка нечетная
    // номер след строки:
    var nextTrNum = Number(currentTrNum)+1;
    // получим строки, у которых атрибут 'num' = nextTrNum
    var $trArray = $('tr[num='+nextTrNum+']');
    // и каждую сделаем видимой:
    $.each($trArray,function(index,value){
      value.style.visibility = 'visible';
      value.style.fontSize = '100%';
    });
  }
});
```

```css
table {width: 100%;}
table td {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
tr.hidden {visibility: hidden; font-size: 0; background-color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>ТАБЛИЦА 1</p>
<table class="table1">
 <tr num="1">
  <td>table 1 td 1</td>
  <td>table 1 td 2</td>
  <td>table 1 td 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="2" class="hidden">
  <td>table 1 td 4</td>
  <td>table 1 td 5</td>
  <td>table 1 td 6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="3">
  <td>table 1 td 7</td>
  <td>table 1 td 8</td>
  <td>table 1 td 9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="4" class="hidden">
  <td>table 1 td 10</td>
  <td>table 1 td 11</td>
  <td>table 1 td 12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="5">
  <td>table 1 td 13</td>
  <td>table 1 td 14</td>
  <td>table 1 td 15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="6" class="hidden">
  <td>table 1 td 16</td>
  <td>table 1 td 17</td>
  <td>table 1 td 18</td>
 </tr>
  <tr num="7">
  <td>table 1 td 16</td>
  <td>table 1 td 17</td>
  <td>table 1 td 18</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<p>ТАБЛИЦА 2</p>
<table class="table2">
 <tr num="1">
  <td>table 2 td 1</td>
  <td>table 2 td 2</td>
  <td>table 2 td 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="2" class="hidden">
  <td>table 2 td 4</td>
  <td>table 2 td 5</td>
  <td>table 2 td 6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="3">
  <td>table 2 td 7</td>
  <td>table 2 td 8</td>
  <td>table 2 td 9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="4" class="hidden">
  <td>table 2 td 10</td>
  <td>table 2 td 11</td>
  <td>table 2 td 12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="5">
  <td>table 2 td 13</td>
  <td>table 2 td 14</td>
  <td>table 2 td 15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr num="6" class="hidden">
  <td>table 2 td 16</td>
  <td>table 2 td 17</td>
  <td>table 2 td 18</td>
 </tr>
   <tr num="7">
  <td>table 1 td 16</td>
  <td>table 1 td 17</td>
  <td>table 1 td 18</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо - для себя решил таким способом -   $(this).next().toggleClass('item-r');
   var fer = this.rowIndex+2
   var res = this.rowIndex+1
   $('.Content tr:nth-child('+ fer +')').toggleClass('item-r');
   $('.FixCol tr:nth-child('+ res +') td').toggleClass('item-rs');
});

Comment: ищем номер строки и дальше передаем номер в nth-child

Comment: Да, так даже лучше получается, без лишних атрибутов всяких

Comment: Спасибо - у вас тоже хороший вариант - спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Находим номер строки которая открывается - и передаем ее в :nth-child()

```
$(".FixCol tr").after().click(function(){

  $(this).next().toggleClass('item-r');
   var fer = this.rowIndex+2
   var res = this.rowIndex+1
   $('.Content tr:nth-child('+ fer +')').toggleClass('item-r');
   $('.FixCol tr:nth-child('+ res +') td').toggleClass('item-rs');
});
```